# The vote counter in the badge tracker is different than the vote cast

Tags: support, badges, voting

For example:

[image]

Please note, we gave the vote cast enough time to update but still it does not match the counter shown in the badge tracker. The thing is, the lady is new to SE and made serial votes, these votes most likely got rolled back, yet they still shown in the tracker but not in the vote cast. I might be wrong but we had a [long chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21314857#21314857) regarding this and this is what we came up with, I could be wrong, but one thing for sure, the two counters do not match.

Comment: Caching is to blame! Again.

Comment: Caching is to blame for the big lapse, but not for the fact that I get 36 or 38 instead of 40. I am looking at what I do when I am not getting the full 40.

Answer (score 2):

The vote cast tracker did catch up with the badge tracker eventually, but very slowly.
It took three or even four days of voting till out of votes for the  Vox Populi badge to be awarded. 
There might have been a few votes to the same user, but I got the impression that when there are votes in a short time, the vote counters do not catch up with them.

Might be worth checking out by people who know what they are talking about.

(I am the lady mentioned by OP.)

Added after a more than a year:
I still see the same problems, even though I am a well established user now.

Comment: Are re-open votes counted against your 40 allowed votes? Today I voted 39 upvotes, 4 close votes and one re-open vote and the warning message said no more votes till the new day.

Comment: I counted the votes, 12 upvotes on questions, 27 on answers.

Comment: Is that on Travel.se?

Comment: Yes, TSE, I do not vote enoug elsewhere to have these problems.

Comment: Hmm, that is a shame because I was going to say it was caused by now deleted posts but as you have > 10K there you're able to see deleted posts you voted on in your profile so it should add up. Strange.

Comment: I will keep an eye out for votes on deleted posts in the future. I am sure it will happen to me again, as it has happened before